# how to ignore "maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack" property which is written in web.config?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I set **"maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack=true"** in my web.config file for the shake of requirement. Everything is ok, but the problem is this global setting ignore my control.focus() property.

Eg:

```
myLable.focus();
```

myLable is not get focused. How can I get focus over controls regardless of  **"maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack"** property? any help would be greatly appreciated...!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

set MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack=false; just before where you want to use focus with your label. This article has detailed discussion how it works underneath [How MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback works](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121505/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/111407-1.aspx)

Comment: it solved the problem. but just wondering, will setting it to false override the web.config setting? coz I don't want to change this for entire website. Only needed in few places....

Comment: It is also available on page level you can reset it to true like this %@ Page MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" %> or in code. This way you can have custom behavior on each page. Or you can use javascript to focus the control.

Answer (score 3):

maintainScrollPositionOnPostBack relies on browser config entries in the Web.Config which are no longer supported or recommended by Microsoft - as it is, the versions of the browsers it supports are antiquated.

Use jQuery to achieve this effect, plus it's cross-browser friendly.

FYI: Here's another was to handle this:

http://www.kodergurl.com/2010/08/maintain-scroll-position-on-post-back.html

Comment: thnx for your info. I'll keep that in mind for second phase, but now I have to deliver the project before deadline.